# Rhythmbox's isn't registering all Last.fm songs in my profile, where is the problem?

Tags: rhythmbox

I've been using this plugin since August, but recently it has been failing: not all the tracks are being registered in my profile. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Last.fm have been experiencing intermittent issues with their scrobbling and library services. 
Take a look at their [Community Forums](http://www.last.fm/forum/21713/_/433934) for known, outstanding issues.